# Change the height of a Windows 8 store XAML ListViewItem height when it's selected

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a XAML ListView and I use the following Template for the ListViewItem:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain" Height=200 d:DesignWidth="720" 
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Code" Style="{StaticResource QuestionTextBlockStyle}" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="RC" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource  QuestionTextBlockStyle}" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textCode" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource AnswerTextBoxStyle}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textRCode" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,5" TextAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding R_Code, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource AnswerTextBoxStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
```

So as you can see the template (gridMain) has a height of 200. I want this to be 400 when the ListViewItem is the selected item and back to 200 when a different ListViewItem is selected.

Can anybody help?

This is a Windows 8 store application so I don't have triggers like WPF.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say `ListViewItem` I will assume this is for a `ListView`. If, however, you intended to mean `GridView` then what you are asking is not possible (in a practical sense). That's because `GridView` creates a clipping container that prevents this. `ListView` on the other hand just uses a `StackPanel` so you can do it. Here's how.

Consider this XAML (just vanilla XAML):

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid Background="Black">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100" Width="100" Background="DimGray">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And then this code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    Grid CurrentGrid;
    private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentGrid != null)
            CurrentGrid.Height = 100;
        if (!e.AddedItems.Any())
            return;
        var container = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(e.AddedItems.First());
        var presenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, 0);
        CurrentGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(presenter, 0) as Grid;
        CurrentGrid.Height = 150;
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<string> _Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
        (Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(x => x.ToString()));
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get { return _Items; } }
}
```

Works like a charm.

[image]

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Jerry, this works really well but if I add a new item to the databound collection after the page has been displayed the ContainerFromItem returns null. Do you have an idea how I can get round this? Thanks

Comment: Make sure your collection is of type ObservableCollection!

Comment: It is Jerry. I only use ObservableCollections.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I've added another questions in relation to my comment. Please have a look to see if you can help me answer it. I can then accept both question as complete then. The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995504/listview-containerfromitem-returns-null-after-a-new-item-is-added-in-windows-8-1

Answer (score 1):

You can use ItemTemplateSelector :

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate DataTemplate1 { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate SelectedDataTemplate { get; set; }



        protected override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected)
            {
               return SelectedDataTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
               return DataTemplate1;
            }
            return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
        }
    }
```

//In your xaml page

```
<common:DataTemplateSelector x:Key="DataTemplateSelector" 
                                    DataTemplate1="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"
                                    SelectedDataTemplate="{StaticResourc DataTemplate2}" />


<DataTemplate x:key="DataTemplate1" />
<DataTemplate x:key="DataTemplate2" />
```

//in your listbox
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelector}"

Comment: Hi MatDev8. I think this is what I need. I have a couple of questions: 1. How does the SelectTemplateCore get fired? It doesn't seem to fire when a ListViewItem is selected? 2. IsSelected doesn't exist of object so I've casted object to ListViewItem, is this what you meant? Thanks

Comment: When your listview is loaded, for all item your selectemplatecore is fired. It was an exemple but you can found information here => http://developingfor.net/2009/01/09/dynamically-switch-wpf-datatemplate/ . Basically, template selector is for use differente template for different data. Like Chris W said, the best way for change an selected item is use blend and change visualstate isSelected like you want. Exemple here => http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtabcontrol-item-templates-and-selectors.html . You are welcome :)