# ListBox ScrollIntoView not working OnNavigatedTo

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm making a timer with adjustable time. For that reason I want to set the time using listboxes (one for minutes and one for seconds). The filling of the listboxes is accomplished using the following code.

```
public EditTime()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        List<Numbers> numbers = new List<Numbers>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(new Numbers() { Number = i });
        }

        listBoxobjM.ItemsSource = numbers;
        listBoxobjS.ItemsSource = numbers;


        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

    }

    public class Numbers
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

In XAML I have the following code for the ListBoxes:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRootM" Margin="65,0,0,0" Width="130">
            <ListBox Background="Transparent"  Margin="10,10,10,10"  BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="listBoxobjM" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Left"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="70" Height="80" x:Name="LbM" Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="48" Foreground="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"  />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRootS" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="130">
            <ListBox Background="Transparent"  Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="listBoxobjS" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                            <StackPanel Width="125" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
                                <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Left"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="70" Height="80" x:Name="LbS" Text="{Binding Number}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="48" Foreground="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"  />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

When I navigate to this page I can select the preselected time (minutes and seconds) using listBoxobjM.SelectedIndex = i; in the following code. I can scroll manually to this Item and see it is selected.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string parameter = e.Parameter as string;
        string[] parts = parameter.Split(';');
        id = int.Parse(parts[0]);
        ....
        DatabaseHelper fetch = new DatabaseHelper();
        TeamType team = fetch.GetTeamType(id);

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            if (i == team.PlayTime.Minutes)
            {
                listBoxobjM.SelectedIndex = i;
                listBoxobjM.ScrollIntoView(listBoxobjM.SelectedIndex);
           }
            if (i == team.PlayTime.Seconds)
            {
                listBoxobjS.SelectedIndex = i;
                listBoxobjS.ScrollIntoView(listBoxobjS.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the Listbox automatically to scroll to the SelectedIndex, but instead the Listbox shows the first Items on top. How can I take care theListBox scrolls to the SelectedIndex?

Comment: Check if your listboxes are actually intialized/populated when entering OnNavigatedTo.

Comment: You might improve your code by making your 2nd `if` an `else if` (unless for some reason Seconds out ranks Minutes), and I would have expected both conditions to `break` out of the for loop when you found one (unless you are looking for the last match, not the first one).  Hard to say without knowing what your code does...just basing this on the general pattern of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`ListBox.ScrollIntoView()` takes an item that's in the ListBox, not an index. ([MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))  So instead of

```
listBoxobjM.ScrollIntoView(listBoxobjM.SelectedIndex);
```

try

```
listBoxobjM.ScrollIntoView(listBoxobjM.SelectedItem);
```

instead.

Comment: 1. The listboxes are populated with the right data: The proper number is selected.

Comment: I'm using twice an if statement because I want both Seconds and Minutes to be selected at its appropriate value. In this way it is. Using the SelectedItem instead of the SelectedIndex I already tried, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the solution myself via an other [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995504/listview-containerfromitem-returns-null-after-a-new-item-is-added-in-windows-8-1). Here they also had problems with the ListView because it was filled with a delay. Using a await Task.Delay (see code) the problem is solved. I thank everybody for his contribution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            if (i == team.PlayTime.Minutes)
            {
                listBoxobjM.SelectedIndex = i;
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                listBoxobjM.ScrollIntoView(listBoxobjM.SelectedItem);
            }
            if (i == team.PlayTime.Seconds)
            {
                listBoxobjS.SelectedIndex = i;
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                listBoxobjS.ScrollIntoView(listBoxobjS.SelectedItem);

            }
        }
```